# How to create a shortcut button to jump to a DialogPreference

Tags: android

I would like to make a button on the front page of the app that jumps to a specific DialogPreference.

The purpose of the button is to be a shortcut to that preference, bypassing having to browse the list of all preferences, since I'm going to be resetting that preference a lot.

---

If it's not possible to make this button, can someone give me the source for DialogPreference (I don't have enough space to download the source tree).

Answer (score 0):

You can use android.provider.Settings.* intent to do this... for example, if you want to open the GPS settings page from your app, use the following code:
Intent myIntent = new Intent( android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
            startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: How do I make my custom ACTION_* from preferences?